# Create popup box on click with value of hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, popup, modal-dialog

Hi i have looked every where for this but cant find a good way of doing it :/

I have a dynamically populated list on my website that looks like this:

```
<li>
  name: blue<br/>
  procesor: blue<br/>
  <div class="right top">2001</div>
  <input type="hidden" name="Description" value="short">
</li>
```

I have been looking for a way to have a small popup show with the contents of the hiddent text field in the list.

I have tried many free modal javascript code but they all seem to either stop working or destroy my template.

Dose anyone know how I could do this. I have no working javascript code as from now and am looking for the best way todo this. It doesn't need to be fancy. Just a white boc with the popup

Comment: Consider a dialog: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: `alert($("[name=Description]").val());`

Comment: problem with alert is the user can click a box to stop it showing witch i dont want also it says the page at url witch just look crap

Comment: also a dialog just dosent look good on mobie view

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add `title` property to `li`:

```
<li title="Some short desc">
...
</li>
```

This should work on all desktop browsers, but not on mobiles.

Another way is to use excellent hint.css from http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/

It does not rely on any JavaScript and rather uses data-* attribute, pseudo elements, content property and CSS3 transitions to create the tooltips. You can fine tune orientation, colours, and even animations.

Comment: sorry should have added i need it to be mobile friendly as most of the sites users about 99% use tablet and mobile devices

Comment: Does popup show on touch/mouse move, or do you need it there permanently? If touch/move then use hint, works really really well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
$(function() {

  $(".list li input[type=hidden]").each(function(index, obj) {
    $(".popup").append($(obj).val() + "<br/>");

  });
  $(".popup").show();
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #E5988A;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px auto;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
}
.disabled {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">

  <li>
    name: blue
    <br/>procesor: blue
    <br/>
    <div class="right top">2001</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Description" value="short" />
  </li>
  <li>
    name: green
    <br/>procesor: gree
    <br/>
    <div class="right top">2002</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Description" value="anothershort">
  </li>

</ul>

<div class="popup"></div>
<div class="disabled"></div>
```

Comment: Hi tried this but the box appears on page load and there is no way to get rid of it

Comment: you may have a close/cross button on it for that
and you may only show the popup when its required not on the page load that's just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: ok well the test dosent work added your code to a page and the moment anyone loads the page the box is there and blocks out the rest of the screen and makes the page unusable

Comment: Yeah I disabled the whole page except popup to make popup more distinguishable. and again you may show popup on a button click or something not on page load. when you'll close the popup just hide the overlay/disable div again. I guess it is simple.

Comment: ok i will see if i can find someone that knows jquery and javascript to fix the code and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

**Html Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

</head>

<body> 
  <div>
      Select <select id = "MyList"></select>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="Description" value="short" id="hiddendiv">
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var select = document.getElementById("MyList");
      var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
      for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          var opt = options[i];
          var el = document.createElement("option");
          el.textContent = opt;
          el.value = opt;
          select.appendChild(el);
      }
      $('#MyList').hover(
        function(){
          var value=$('input').val();
          alert(value);
        }, function() {
        }
      )

});
```

Comment: Hi sorry this dose not help my problem is with li enliments no a select box and there could be an infenant number of them on a page there is no way to know as this is determened by user input so this option dose not really work